# It won't hover or let me click on images in my gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, image

Since I've added this cropping effect (http://jsfiddle.net/BPEhD/2/) to the images in my gallery, there is no hover state on the images and it won't let click on them either. The pointer cursor appears when I hover over them, but it won't bring up the panel when I click on it. How can I solve this?

HTML:

```
<div id="thumbsWrapper">
<div id="content">

<p class="crop">
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg"/></p>
<p class="crop">        
<img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2.jpg"/></p>
<p class="crop"> 
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1.jpg"/></p>

<div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="panel">
<div id="wrapper">
<a id="prev"></a>
<a id="next"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbsWrapper{
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}
#content{
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
left:0px;
display:none;
} 
.crop{
float:left;
margin:.5em 10px .5em 0;
overflow:hidden; /* this is important */
position:relative; /* this is important too */
border:1px solid #ccc;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
.crop img{
position:absolute;
top:-50px;
left:-50px;
}
#content img{
float:left;
margin:5px 0px 5px 5px;
cursor:pointer;
opacity:0.4;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40);
}
#panel{
background-color:#ddd;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
height:0px;
text-align:center;
z-index:999;
}
#panel img{
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #000;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111;
box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111;
display:none;
}
```

Relevant JS:

```
$(function() {
/* this is the index of the last clicked picture */
var current = -1;
/* number of pictures */
var totalpictures = $('#content img').size();
/* speed to animate the panel and the thumbs wrapper */
var speed   = 500;

/* show the content */
$('#content').show();

/*
when the user resizes the browser window,
the size of the picture being viewed is recalculated;
 */
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    var $picture = $('#wrapper').find('img');
    resize($picture);
});

/*
when hovering a thumb, animate it's opacity
for a cool effect;
when clicking on it, we load the corresponding large image;
the source of the large image is stored as
the "alt" attribute of the thumb image
 */
$('#content > img').hover(function () {
    var $this   = $(this);
    $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'1.0'},200);
},function () {
    var $this   = $(this);
    $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'0.4'},200);
}).bind('click',function(){
    var $this   = $(this);

    /* shows the loading icon */
    $('#loading').show();

    $('<img alt="">').load(function(){
        $('#loading').hide();
        if($('#wrapper').find('img').length) return;
        current     = $this.index();
        var $theImage   = $(this);
        /*
        After it's loaded we hide the loading icon
        and resize the image, given the window size;
        then we append the image to the wrapper
        */
        resize($theImage);

        $('#wrapper').append($theImage);
        /* make its opacity animate */
        $theImage.fadeIn(800);

        /* and finally slide up the panel */
        $('#panel').animate({'height':'100%'},speed,function(){
            /*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the selector you're using to match your image tags. You're using the child selector which only selects direct children of the selected element (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)). Since (I'm guessing) you've added `p` tags around your images to apply the cropping effect, the selector is no longer returning the images.

Try updating your code as follows:

```
$('#content img').hover(function () {
    var $this   = $(this);
    $this.stop().animate({'opacity':'1.0'},200);
}
```

Note that this will select all elements that are descendants of the content `div` (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)) so, depending on what you're doing, you may want to consider a more specific selector.

Just a friendly hint, but a fully functioning fiddle demonstrating the issue would make it easier to help.

Comment: The prev and next arrows in the panel aren't working now. Any idea how I can solve that problem?

Comment: Have you posted all the code? If it was working previously, I'd check any selectors you're using related to that functionality which may have been affected by the changes you've made to the HTML structure.